# Data is not going into database and that's the reason it is not routing to id of that enterd data in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, routes

**Controller code:**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    def show 
    end

    def new 
    end

    def create
        @item = Item.new(item_params)

        @item.save
        redirect_to @item
    end

    private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:mobile, :company)
  end

end
```

**New.html.erb code**

```
<%= form_for :item , url: items_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :mobile %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :mobile %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :company %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :company %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

One more thing i don't think i am using right parameters in the private method for require. If it is so then let me know what i should use?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that `@item.save works`. Only `redirect_to @item` if save was successful, general practice is to `render new` again if it failed and display any error messages in new.html.erb - then you might have a better idea as to why it failed.

Comment: Any reason why you are using a symbol as opposed to an instance variable in your form declaration for `item`?

Comment: rails guides used instance variables and i am following those.......in rails guides site they used it similarly this way...i just changed the :article to this :item.

Answer (score 0):

1.) write `@item = Item.new(item_params)` in the new action.

2.) change your file name from New.html.erb to new.html.erb
if this does not solve your problem,may be you are writng the column names wrong. Hope this will be helpful

Comment: on point 1) why would you do that? nothing is posted to the new action.